# How to solve Solr IndexUpgrader not being able to find _md6.si?

Tags: indexing, solr, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade a Solr 4.x index to Solr 5.x (so I can upgrade it all the way to 8.x). The Solr installation itself is version 4.5.1.

The IndexUpgraderTool complains that it can't find the file _md6.si in my index. It doesn't exist in any of our indexes, and there is no information about the file on the internet. I tried a text search inside all of the index files, thinking it might be a broken link of sorts, but I wasn't able to find it that way either.

The stacktrace is below. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Temp\Dev_feature\default\index\_md6.si
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory.openInput(MMapDirectory.java:196)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene40.Lucene40SegmentInfoReader.read(Lucene40SegmentInfoReader.java:51)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:361)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:457)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:912)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:758)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:453)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.listCommits(DirectoryReader.java:277)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader.upgrade(IndexUpgrader.java:151)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader.main(IndexUpgrader.java:74)
```

Comment: The file name will be a generated file name for your index specifically, so you won't find any information from the filename itself. Have you tried committing and then optimizing the index (so that all the segments gets rewritten) before running the index upgrader?

Comment: @MatsLindh Looks like optimising it did the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good idea to run optimize on the index before running index upgrader - that way you'll get a clean index that the index upgrader can work with. The index files will be merged and rewritten as a single index, and any lingering deleted documents, etc. will be removed.

You can generally call optimize by issuing an `optimize` command to the update handler:

```
/update?optimize=true
```